# Как сортировать файл по числу в начале строки?

Tags: python

У меня есть файл в котором несколько строк выглядят так:

```
43 $ name1
765 $ name2
98765 $ name3
1 $ name4
2456 $ name5
```

И мне нужно его отсортировать, что бы сверху был файл наибольшим числом в файле(name3) и снизу с наименьшим(name4) и между ними также отсортировано(больше число - выше)

Все строки в файле отличаются только цифрой и именем - 5000 строк в сумме

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: [i.split(' ') for i in f.read().split('\n')]. Так вы получите лист со строками, где строки тоже разбиты по пробелу. Далее сортируете лист по 1 значению подлиста ВАШ_ЛИСТ.sort(key = lambda x: x[0]) . Всё, ваш массив отсортирован по цифрам, можете перезаписывать файл

Comment: Загрузить файл в массив построчно, отсортировать массив, сохранить массив в тот же файл

Comment: Открываете, считываете, сортируете, записываете, закрываете.

Comment: @dhvcc а какое отношение имеет разбивка строки на слова к вопросу?

Comment: Обычный sorted и natsorted сортирует по первой второй цифре

Comment: А мне нужно именно по числу

Comment: Далее сортируете лист по 1 значению подлиста ВАШ_ЛИСТ.sort(key = lambda x: x[0]) . Всё, ваш массив отсортирован по цифрам, можете перезаписывать файл

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я дописывал ответ

Comment: @dhvcc Так может тогда как ответ оформить?))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_list = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_list.append(line.split(' '))
    new_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in new_list:
        f.write(' '.join(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('ваш файл', 'r+') as f:
    l=[i.split(' ') for i in f.read().split('\n')]
    l.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write('\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in l]))
```

Вроде что-то такое, протестировать не успел

Comment: Увы сортирует по цифре, а не числу. На выходе получился файл где 1924 ниже чем 2

Comment: @Кевин да, забыл привести к инту :/

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r+')
lines = sorted(map(lambda x: x.split(), file.readlines()), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
file.seek(0)
file.write('\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in lines]))
file.close()
```

Comment: Также рабочее решение =)